# How to set the "Keep this build forever" from within a build

Tags: jenkins

How can I get a build to modify its own "Keep this build forever" setting?

Inside the build.xml, this the  setting.

```
   <keepLog>true</keepLog>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Execute system Groovy Script put:

```
build.keepLog(true)
```